# Place details - Attributes eligible for permanent storage in database

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details provides various details of Places.

Apart from **place_id**, is it legal to store any other attributes of Place API in permanent storage ( database etc)?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Maps Platform Terms of Service section 3.2.4(a)](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license)

> Customer may cache limited amounts of Google Maps Content if cache: (a) is only for the purpose of improving Customer Application performance due to network latency, or intermittent connectivity; (b) is secure; (c) is stored for less than 30 consecutive calendar days; (d) is not redistributed; (e) does not prevent Google from accurately calculating Customer's Service usage levels; (f) does not modify attribution in any way; and (g) does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Google Maps Content or Services.

[Place IDs are exempt from 3.2.4(a)](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#save-id)

> Place IDs are exempt from the caching restrictions stated in Section 3.2.4(a) of the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service. You can therefore store place ID values for later use.

*"Apart from place_id, is it legal to store any other attributes of Place API in permanent storage ( database etc)?"*

Apparently, the answer is no.